# Creating a Stacks toString from scratch?

Tags: java, stack

I am creating a Stack from scratch and am having difficulties creating the toString() method. I have the rest of the stack completed. I am creating one from scratch because it is an assignment. If I could get a hint of what Im doing wrong, that would be very helpful, thanks!!

```
public class MyStack<Type> {
    private Node top;
    private int size;

    private class Node{
        private Node next;
        private Type current;

        public Node() {
            next = null;
            current = null;
        }
    }

    public void push(Type item) {
        Node old = top;
        top = new Node();

        top.current = item;
        top.next = old;

        size++;

    }

    public Type pop() {
        Type type = null;
        if(top != null) {
            type = top.current;
            top = top.next;
            size--;
        }

        return type;
    }

    public Type peek(){
        return top.current;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        boolean result = false;
        if(size > 0) {
            result = false;
        } else{
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() { // this is where I'm having issues.
        String result = "[";
        if(top != null) {
            while(top.next != null) {
                result = result + top.current;
            }

        }

        result = result + "]";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: *If I could get a hint of what I'm doing wrong* You didn't tell us what is the problem.

Comment: @Guy Sorry, So basically my toString is not printing anything out even when I call it, or use the push method. I know that my push and pop are working correctly, but the toString prints nothing out, it doesnt even go in the while loop.

Comment: It is better to state the problem in the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `top` to traverse Stack, List, Queue, Tree or any other collection you will implement. Because you will loose reference to the beginning of this collection. Instead create temporary variable to traverse it.

```
//toString in MyStack class
public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    Node temp = top;
    while(temp != null){
        s+= temp + " ";
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    return s;
}
```

---

```
//toString in Node class
public String toString(){
     return current +"
}

public Node getNext(){
    return next;
}
```

Comment: When I use this solution I get an exception at this line    'private Node next;'

Comment: @thatsnifty add the `getNext()` method to the `Node` class.

Comment: @Yoda I am now getting a nullpointerexception at line 'temp = temp.getNext()'

Comment: @thatsnifty that is impossible.

Comment: @Yoda Im really not sure why I am getting that? But I am getting it.

Comment: @Yoda I fixed the issue!! The issue was in my while loop! I was using top instead of temp. Thank you!!!